# gdal rasterizelayer constant value

Tags: gdal, rasterization, gdal-rasterize

How do you rasterize a polygon layer into a raster so all cells covered by polygons (i.e. not NoData) will be set to a constant value?

I do this to set cell according to attribute values:

```
gdal.RasterizeLayer(rasterHdl, [1], featureLayer, options=["ATTRIBUTE=%s" % attributeName])
```

... but how about burning in a constant?

Comment: is a "burn value" what you are looking for? http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html

Comment: pass -burn 1 to the arguments

Answer (score 1):

To pass a constant burn value, e.g. 1, using the GDAL Python bindings:

```
ds = gdal.RasterizeLayer(rasterHdl, [1], featureLayer, burn_values=[1])
ds = None
```